# exploded string manipulation

Tags: php, explode

I have already seen examples for string manipulation using "explode" but none of them does my job..

I have an array of exploded strings:

```
$grand_result = 12,5,7,3,2,1 ;
$grandparent_id =  explode(",",$grand_result);
```

- i want to insert some values in db having id = `$grand_result` except first value returned (12) in this case
- `$grand_result` can have many values i want to fetch only first 7 values..
  how can i do that ...thanks in advance

Comment: You have an array with exploded integers.

Comment: don't store comma-separated values in a database column, normalize your database

Comment: @MarkBaker this value is returned by a stored function...thanks for concern

Comment: You can use array_slice to get the portion of the array you're after. What exactly are you trying to do with the database?

Comment: Where are the quotes around the value of `$grand_result`?

Comment: @SimonBrahan these r user_ids i want to distribute some amount to the people with these ids..values are different for person with first id('12') and different for rest 6...

Comment: i am a newbie to stackoverflow i dont have reputation here...why downvote i couldn't understand...

Comment: @barmar i have put code becase it is working..there is no need for quotes

Comment: If you don't put quotes around it, it's not a string that you can explode. It just sets `$grand_result` to `1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use array_slice

```
$output = array_slice($grandparent_id, 0, 7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Set Limit of explode

```
$grand_result = 12,5,7,3,2,1 ;
$grandparent_id =  explode(",",$grand_result,8);


unset($grandparent_id[7]); or $grandparent_id = array_slice($grandparent_id, 0, 7);
```

Comment: Should be `explode(",",$grand_result,8);` - will return 7 elements and rest of string as 8th element.

Comment: You are missing a ')' after the '8' to end the explode statement

Comment: thanks all...array_slice worked for me...

Answer (score 0):

```
$grand_result = "12,5,7,3,2,1" ;
$grandparent_id =  explode(",",$grand_result);
```

first update

```
$avoid = grandparent_id[0];
foreach ($grandparent_id as $id) {
    if ($avoid != $id) {
         //run your update query
    }
}
```

second fetch

```
$query = "select * from `table_name` where id in (".$grand_result.") limit 7";
```